# What is the current status of airside connections at LAX?

Tags: transit, lax

I know that Terminals 4-8 have always been connected by tunnels, and a new bridge connecting the Tom Bradley International Terminal with Terminal 4 (and thus 5-8) at the airside was recently constructed. I also know that there are no physical airside connections among Terminals 1-3 and TBIT.

Recently, Delta Air Lines moved its operations from Terminal 5 to Terminals 2 and 3, and there is now a connection bus that operates between these two terminals. I also read some news that there may be a bus connecting Terminal 3 with TBIT, though I'm not sure.

- Is the airside bus between Terminals 2 and 3 fully airside, or does it require a security check?
- Is there an airside bus between Terminal 3 and the Tom Bradley International Terminal? If so, does it require a security check?
- Do any of these buses have restrictions on who can use it (e.g. does moving from TBIT to Terminal 3 require a Terminal 3 boarding pass)?
- What about Terminal 1? Does it have any sort of airside connections to the other terminals?

After doing some research, I found this: https://pro.delta.com/content/agency/us/en/news/news-archive/2017/may-2017/delta_s-relocation-to-lax-terminals-2-and-3-begins-evening-of-fr.html

> Immediately following the move, Delta customers will enjoy:
>
> - Faster and more convenient connections to flights operated by Delta’s joint venture and SkyTeam partners in Terminals 2, 3 and TBIT via an airside bus that prevents customers from having to leave and re-enter the secure area

Are these buses restricted to Delta passengers, or can other passengers use them? Do they allow passengers to go both ways, or can passengers only go one way on one or more of these shuttles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For up-to-date news, the [FlyerTalk thread](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/delta-air-lines-skymiles/1737533-lax-2017-terminal-move-definitive-thread-32.html) concerning the [terminal move](https://www.wired.com/2017/05/lax-pulling-off-massive-frenzied-terminal-reshuffle/) and other aspects of flying Delta through LAX is pretty reliable.

As the [One Mile at a Time blog points out](http://onemileatatime.boardingarea.com/2017/05/10/delta-lax-terminal-change/), unfortunately, the "Sky Way" connecting Terminals 2 and 3 is not expected to open until at least 2023.

> Before we move on, though, I regret to inform you of the biggest headache of all: there will not be a convenient airside connection between T2 and T3 for a while. That’s right: there will be airside shuttles, but if you land at T2 and have a connection at T3, you’ll need to allow yourself extra time to get between gates.

The shuttle bus is completely airside and no screening is involved; the [map](https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/airports-and-aircraft/airports/los-angeles.html) is posted on Delta's website. From T2 it departs from gate <del>22A</del> 21, at T3 it uses at gate "35P" adjacent to gate 35, and at TBIT it arrives at the north bus gate.

The shuttle between T2 and T3 is supposed to run about every 6 minutes, and the ride time between the two is about ten minutes. The shuttle connecting TBIT to T2 and T3 is supposed to run about every 7 minutes, with a published journey time of 13 minutes. Delta is not the only airline using those terminals— part of the move was to make it easier to connect to partner airlines— and there is no requirement that you be a Delta passenger to use them once airside. That said, if the terminal or buses become very crowded, we cannot say that they wouldn't impose a check, to ensure that space on the bus is available for people who really do need to change terminals to catch a flight.

There is no airside connection to Terminal 1.

Comment: Can it be ridden from TBIT to Terminal 2-3? The table on Delta's website doesn't mention this at the airside, only on international arrival.

Comment: This table: https://www.delta.com/content/dam/delta-www/lax/images/destinations/aem-destination/delta_lax_chart_042417_v02_Desktop.jpg

Comment: Ah. As I noted, if you are an international arrival at TBIT, you will go through customs and immigration processing and need to re-clear security to make any onward connections. That is why you cannot take the shuttle from TBIT back to 2 or 3, because it is airside only.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But you didn't answer my question in the top comment: can it be ridden on the airside from TBIT to Terminals 2-3, for instance if I wanted to get there from Terminal 4, or can it not be ridden that way? The table above only mentions how to get there on international arrival at TBIT, not if you're on the airside.

Comment: Anecdotally, yes, you can ride from TBIT back to T2/T3 as reported in [blog posts](http://renespoints.boardingarea.com/2017/07/25/delta-air-lines-t2t3tbit-transfers-day-long-avgeek-fun-lax/), for example, at least as of summer.