# JFK to Adelaide with LAX layover

Tags: connecting-flights, lax, delta-air-lines, virgin-australia

I will be flying delta JFK to Adelaide with a LAX layover. the layover is 1h and 42min. Once I get down at LAX, will there be signs that tells me exactly where to get the airside bus from ? I will be landing in T2 or 3 and then will have to go to TBIT. my bags will be checked all the way thru.

Also, does anyone know which departure gates Virgin Australia normally departs from TBIT? I am trying to look at the airport map and see how far I have to walk once the airsidebus drops me at TBIT. This is my first international trip and am travelling solo. Not sure if I made a wise decision but will definitely be a learning experience. Thanks.

Comment: Of interest: *[What is the current status of airside connections at LAX?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106542)*

Answer (score 3):

From [Delta's website](https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/airports-and-aircraft/airports/los-angeles.html), it appears that the shuttles from T2 and T3 depart from near gates 22A and 35P (respectively).  There will almost certainly be signs to guide you there, but knowing what to expect might help you know what to look for.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The exact departure gate may vary from day to day, and unusual circumstances might lead to your flight leaving from an unusual gate.  Even if somebody on this site tells you what gate the flight leaves from, that information may be wrong on the day you travel.

However, there will be monitors all over the airport telling you what gate each flight departs from.  In my experience, at US airports, they're usually sorted A-Z by destination (whereas, in the UK, they tend to be sorted by departure time), so it's very easy to find which gate you'll be flying from.

Note that many international flights are what are called "code shares".  That means that the flight has multiple flight numbers, corresponding to the different airlines that sell tickets on that plane. So, for example, your flight might have one flight number for Virgin Australia, another for Delta and maybe more for other partner airlines. The monitors often don't have space to display all the flight numbers at once, so they typically cycle through them.

And you can always ask for help. If you can't see anyone else to ask, just go to a random gate where there's a member of staff who isn't dealing with any passengers at the moment. They'll be happy to help you or direct you to somebody who can help.

Comment: "The exact departure gate may vary from day to day": this is a fairly severe understatement; it might be more accurate to say "from minute to minute."  More precisely, it is not at all uncommon for the departure gate to change after boarding passes have been printed, even as late as half an hour before the scheduled departure or sometimes later.  If the flight is delayed, the gate can (and often does) change  *after* the scheduled departure time.

Comment: @phoog These days, I hardly ever get a gate number on my boarding pass. And, yes, they can change at short notice, but that's less common for long-haul flights such as the one that the asker is taking. I've taken the same flight from Minneapolis to London twice a year for most of the last five years and it's almost always departed from gate G5 or G6, for example.